# Rotate GameObject on Z axis only C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation, gameobject

Found this answer here: 
[Rotate a gameobject in Unity](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29419514/2108547)

I have found this very useful but I want to assign the rotation only to the Z axis, which I can't get to work.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Rotation : MonoBehaviour {
    public GameObject Player;
    public GameObject PlayerCube;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        var playerMapPos = Player;
        var playerWorldPos = PlayerCube;
        PlayerCube.transform.rotation  = Player.transform.rotation;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
    }
}
```

Comment: Post your attempted rotation code

Comment: Please, read the tag descriptions before using them. `unity` tag has nothing to do with Unity game engine.

Answer (score 1):

To limit the axis of the rotations you need to use Euler angles instead of Quaternions. First, convert the rotation Quaternion to Euler angles, then modify the rotation as you want (assign all axes except y to be 0), and then convert it back.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Quaternion too but need to specific how many you like to rotate and what Vector3 direction to apply (ie: Vector3.up)

```
PlayerCube.transform.rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(angle, Vector3.up);
```